# Calculation in a QML file?

Tags: qt, qml

I got the following code that doesn't work (in a QML file - PixelAdapter.qml) :

```
Item {
    id: pixelAdapterId

    property int in
    property int alpha
    property int out

    out = in * 10 + alpha

}
```

I tried :

```
pixelAdapterId.out = pixelAdapterId.in * 10 + pixelAdapterId.alpha

PixelAdapter.out: PixelAdapter.in * 10 + PixelAdapter.alpha
```

but everything doesn't work. I feel like I'm not doing something usual in QML but  I HAVE to do some calculations with my properties, and "bind" the result of it to another property.
What do I have to modify ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply bind it:

```
Rectangle {
   width: 100
   height: 100
   focus: true

   property int in
   property int alpha
   property int out: 10*in + alpha

   Keys.onReturnPressed: {
      console.log(out);
      in = 5; alpha =10;
      console.log(out);
      in = 6;
      console.log(out);
   }
}
```

You'll get meaningful results as soon as you'll bind useful values to the parameters.

Comment: This seems to work but it doesn't... I'll try to explain.
The thing is that in my software uses 2 bindings with this QML file. One binding is on the "in" value and the other on the "out" value.
And when I start my software, when I FIRST change my "in" value, the bind on the "out" value gets the new value. This works.
But when I change the value again, the "out" doesn't update... and the thing is that the value will constantly change in my software :/

Does someone got an idea about it ?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding... If I tru to bind again to a new value I get that out is kept up to date. Look at the example in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you have to be very careful about is accidentally resetting/breaking your property bindings.

For example if you have:

```
Rectangle {
   property int x
   property int y: x + 1
   property int z: 2 * y
}
```

Then you can execute some JavaScript somewhere that does `x = 5`, and then y and z will automatically update due to the binding.

However, if you do something like `y = 6` in your JavaScript, then it breaks the binding, and y will no longer update when x changes.

This has caused me a great deal of grief in the past. Not sure if this helps with your question but I thought I'd throw it out there.